# rename of fuse-jna isn't working

Tags: java, rename, jna, fuse

i want to run the memoryfs example in the fuse-jna, but when i call rename it says no such file and i can't rename a file. i have found a bug in rename

```
public int rename(final String path, final String newName)
{
    final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
    if (p == null) {
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
    }
    final MemoryPath newParent = getParentPath(newName);
    if (newParent != null) {
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
    }
    if (!(newParent instanceof MemoryDirectory)) {
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOTDIR;
    }
    p.delete();
    ((MemoryDirectory) newParent).add(p);
    return 0;
}
```

the ! should be = in

```
if (newParent != null) {
    return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
}
```

now i can move a file correctly but i just can't rename, is there a bug in the example? and what should i do to make it right? 
   thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i notice that the latest version works fine. and the rename is correct！